# Setting reminders in iPhone and android using AS3

Tags: android, iphone, actionscript-3, sqlite, flash-cs5.5

I need to set a popup reminder in iphone and android app, whether the app is active or not. How can this be done using as3 and flash cs5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the capabilities class : 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html
You can tell under which os your as3 app is running.If it's android, you can write some native java code and wire it(i m thinking sockets) to your app to show an alert.
For iphone,i don't know if you can.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I am new to this. Can u explain a little more.. thanks in advance.